# AngularJs ,Bootstrap Modal form cant get to look correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

When i have the code run it works but I can get the output how I want. code is here https://jsfiddle.net/RLQhh/6357/

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <form name="registration" ngnovalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-email ng-valid-minlength">
        <div class="modal-header ng-scope">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Registration</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body ng-scope" id="modalbody">

            <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" required="required"><br>
                <p ng-show="registration.username.$touched &amp;&amp; registration.username.$error.required" class="ng-hide">Please enter a Username!</p>
                <p ng-show="registration.username.$error.pattern" class="ng-hide">Please enter a Valid Username (No special characters)!</p>


                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" required="required"><br>
                <p ng-show="registration.email.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.email.$touched" class="ng-hide">Please enter a valid email!</p>


                <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password1" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength" required="required"><br>
                <p ng-show="registration.password1.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.password1.$touched" class="ng-hide">Passwords must be at least 6 characters!</p>

                <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="user.password2" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength" required="required"><br>
                <p ng-show="registration.password2.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.password2.$touched" class="ng-hide">Passwords must be at least 6 characters!</p>
            </div>




        </form>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit(user)">
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the form to look centered and in the correct header body footer section. Instead every time i change the code or css the form removes itself from the body and the footer becomes way off. Im not sure if this is for the fact im using Bootstrap and angularjs or not.

[image]

Comment: You have a col div here: `<div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">` but you didn't place it inside a row div. Check out the documentation on how to use Bootstrap's grid system here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro. You may also want to look at their CSS for forms: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms

Comment: Doesnt change anything in the modal

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header ng-scope">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Registration</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body ng-scope" id="modalbody">
                <form name="registration" ngnovalidate="" class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-email ng-valid-minlength">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user.username" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" required="required"><br>
                        <p ng-show="registration.username.$touched &amp;&amp; registration.username.$error.required" class="ng-hide">Please enter a Username!</p>
                        <p ng-show="registration.username.$error.pattern" class="ng-hide">Please enter a Valid Username (No special characters)!</p>


                        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern" required="required"><br>
                        <p ng-show="registration.email.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.email.$touched" class="ng-hide">Please enter a valid email!</p>


                        <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password1" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength" required="required"><br>
                        <p ng-show="registration.password1.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.password1.$touched" class="ng-hide">Passwords must be at least 6 characters!</p>

                        <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" ng-model="user.password2" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength" required="required"><br>
                        <p ng-show="registration.password2.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.password2.$touched" class="ng-hide">Passwords must be at least 6 characters!</p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit(user)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check opening/closing tags of form there.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code a little. I think that you put your  in a wrong way. Try this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="signup" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header ng-scope">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span
                        aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="modal-title">Registration</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body ng-scope" id="modalbody">
                <div class="row">
                    <form name="registration" ngnovalidate=""
                          class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-email ng-valid-minlength">
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"
                                   ng-model="user.username"
                                   ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/"
                                   class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern"
                                   required="required"><br>

                            <p ng-show="registration.username.$touched &amp;&amp; registration.username.$error.required"
                               class="ng-hide">Please enter a Username!</p>

                            <p ng-show="registration.username.$error.pattern" class="ng-hide">Please enter a Valid
                                Username
                                (No special characters)!</p>


                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email"
                                   ng-required="true" ng-pattern="/^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{2,}$/"
                                   class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-valid-email ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-pattern"
                                   required="required"><br>

                            <p ng-show="registration.email.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.email.$touched"
                               class="ng-hide">
                                Please enter a valid email!</p>


                            <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1" placeholder="Password"
                                   ng-model="user.password1" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6"
                                   class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength"
                                   required="required"><br>

                            <p ng-show="registration.password1.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.password1.$touched"
                               class="ng-hide">Passwords must be at least 6 characters!</p>

                            <input type="password" name="password2" id="password2" placeholder="Confirm Password"
                                   ng-model="user.password2" ng-required="true" ng-minlength="6"
                                   class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-valid-minlength"
                                   required="required"><br>

                            <p ng-show="registration.password2.$invalid &amp;&amp; registration.password2.$touched"
                               class="ng-hide">Passwords must be at least 6 characters!</p>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="submit(user)">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope it help you...

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/r4LdT this is what it looks like when i use your code. as you can see it is still off

Comment: I added a row div that I had forgotten!